# In what timezone did the deadline for the cheap Windows 8 upgrade fall?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I planned on upgrading to Windows 8 using the special cheap offer. However, I only recieved my newly purchased PC on the 31st of January.

The upgrade offer ran until the 31st, however I wonder if the offer ended after 23:59 on the 31st in every timezone or that it ended after 23:59 on the 31st in a specific timezone.

I cannot find anywhere where it specifies which of the two it was.

Comment: Just guessing but it's logical to assume it expires at midnight within the timezone that you originally purchased the PC in.  Although, this is Microsoft we're talking about...

Comment: You are right this is to localized.  There really is no way of knowing this if its not already on the website.

Comment: I've let this stay open for now and will let the community vote. See Meta: [Are questions about the Windows 8 upgrade offer too localized?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6262/are-questions-about-the-windows-8-upgrade-offer-too-localized)

Comment: I have to ask the reason you are going to use the more expensive offer to purchase Windows 8? The only difference is that in order to get the coupon code you must registered your purchase. You will still be able to get the $14.99 price on say Feb 2nd 2013 because of that coupon code used at checkout, using the exact same upgrade tool, used for the other offer. If this is because your new pc is not eligible, the solution is simply, use your current pc to purchase the code **today** to avoid the time crunch.  I bought all my copies on a single computer.

Comment: @Ramhound The PC I purchased does not come with a copy of Windows 7. I have an old copy of Windows XP lying around that I don't use, I plan to upgrade from there.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels - As I indicated purchase it today if you want, get the license key, don't risk the chance of the price increasing on you.  The Upgrade Assistance Tool used to purchase it doesn't care what operating system, the only thing I must worn you about is that, the downloader will only grab a 32-bit installation.  If you want a 64-bit installation the downloader must be ran from a x64-bit installation.  **All you need to download the image is the license key, and this can be done, at any point in time.**  There isn't any reason you cannot go from 32-bit XP to 64-bit Windows 8.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the tip, I'll definitely do that!

Comment: @MatthijsWessels - Happy to help.

Comment: I voted for reopening ([more information](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6262/are-questions-about-the-windows-8-upgrade-offer-too-localized)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're referring to [this offer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/upgrade-offer), then the upgrade time frame is open until 28th Feb. You only need to have purchased your new PC before 31st Jan.

Generally, it seems that since Microsoft has explicitly specified the countries in which this offer is available and set up regional pages for any of these countries, and there's no specific time zone information available, it's probably safe to assume your country's time zone will be used.

Comment: I meant [the other offer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/home). However, the question is also valid for the offer you mentioned: What timezone do they use to determine it's the 31st.

Comment: If it's about the 30 bucks offer to upgrade from any previous Windows version (and I assume you don't have any Windows yet), you can just buy it now by downloading any of the trial versions of Windows that Microsoft offers for download and buy it from there. You'll only be legally using it once you've got the PC with the older version of Windows installed, though.

Comment: Based on your last comment, I feel confident enough to assume that it's a per timezone deal. I've accepted your answer, but maybe for the format, it would be better if you include your last comment in the answer. Otherwise it might seem I accepted your original answer.